# Pass data between View controllers without using prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicontainerview

I have a table view which is embedded in a container view on my main view controller. In my main VC I have a Navigation Bar which has a bar button item that goes to another View controller, which for demonstration purposes I'll call View controller 2. When I hit save on view controller 2 I have an unwind segue to my main vc (the one with the container view). My question is how do I then pass that data to my container view's child.

NOTE: I cannot use NSUserDefaults as I have a custom class which I want to transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a delegate to handle this.When 'unwind segue ' was called,just call  the delegate for your child view controller. This is the best way.

Comment: I'm very happy you accepted my answer.But I found a better solution about this problem.You can get child view controllers easily,and add a public method in the one you want to do something with.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data to be shared by all views, you could consider a singleton class - effectively global data.

[Here's a tutorial which explains how to use it](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)